# console won't log array of divs

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm making a connect four game and right now I'm trying to log an array of every div that's in certain column of the board when that column is clicked. I am able to log the array from the first index to the last. Now I wan't to log the array from the last index to the first. My function looks like this.

```
`function dropChip(col) {
    for(let i = col.length-1; i < col.length; i--) {
        console.log(col[i]);
    }
}`
```

What confuses me is I can go console.log(col); and see all six items. But I can't look at them from reverse?(As I need to check if the bottom div is empty because the chips need to be stacked. Also is using the DOM for the game logic a good idea? I did it this way in a previous version I made and was told it was bad design, but I don't know another way or how to do it with JS) looking at them this way breaks the game? Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? thanks:)

```js
const board = document.querySelectorAll(".slot");

for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
 board[i].addEventListener('click', selectColumn);
}

function selectColumn(evt) {
 let column = evt.target.id;
 let columnArray = [];

 for(let i=0; i < board.length; i++) {
  if(column === board[i].id) columnArray.push(board[i]);
 }
 dropChip(columnArray);
}

function dropChip(col) {
 for(let i = col.length-1; i < col.length; i--) {
  console.log(col[i]);
 }
}
```

```css
/** {
 border: 1px solid red;
}*/

*, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background-color: #e6e9ef;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.board-wrapper {
 /*display: flex;*/
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 100px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.board {
 display: flex;
 background-color: #00c;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 max-width: 706px;
 padding: 3px;
 /*margin: auto;*/
}

.board > div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 border: 3px solid #00c;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
}

.board > div:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 7px;
 left: 7px;
 background-color: #00c;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 13px #0606aa;

}

.board > div:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: -999em;
 bottom: -999em;
 transition: all .5s ease;
 background-color: transparent;
}

.board > div:hover:after {
 background-color: #00c;
}

.board > div.counter {
 /*display: block;
 padding: 0;*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: auto;
 height: 100px;
 border: none;
 background-color: #e6e9ef;
 z-index: 100;
}

.board > div.counter:after {
 /*content: "";*/
 /*display: block;*/
 /*padding: 0;*/
 height: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 background-color: red;
 top: 0;
 /*left: 0;
 right: auto;*/
 border-radius: 50%;
 transition: transform .5s ease, opacity .2s ease;
 /*transform: translateX(0);*/
 z-index: 100;
 opacity: 0;
}

.board > div.counter:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 15px;
 right: auto;
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: red;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #cc0000;
 z-index: 101;
 transition: transform .5s ease, opacity .2s ease;
 /*transform: translateX(0);*/
 opacity: 0;
}

.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover ~ .counter:after{transform:translateX(14px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover ~ .counter:after{transform:translateX(114px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover ~ .counter:after{transform:translateX(214px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover ~ .counter:after{transform:translateX(314px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover ~ .counter:after{transform:translateX(414px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover ~ .counter:after{transform:translateX(514px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover ~ .counter:after{transform:translateX(614px);opacity: 1;}

.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+1):hover ~ .counter:before{transform:translateX(14px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+2):hover ~ .counter:before{transform:translateX(114px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+3):hover ~ .counter:before{transform:translateX(214px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+4):hover ~ .counter:before{transform:translateX(314px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+5):hover ~ .counter:before{transform:translateX(414px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+6):hover ~ .counter:before{transform:translateX(514px);opacity: 1;}
.board > div:nth-of-type(7n+7):hover ~ .counter:before{transform:translateX(614px);opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Connect Four</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="board-wrapper">
  <div class="board">
   <div class="slot" id="col-1"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-2"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-3"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-4"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-5"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-6"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-7"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-1"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-2"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-3"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-4"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-5"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-6"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-7"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-1"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-2"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-3"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-4"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-5"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-6"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-7"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-1"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-2"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-3"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-4"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-5"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-6"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-7"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-1"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-2"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-3"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-4"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-5"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-6"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-7"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-1"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-2"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-3"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-4"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-5"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-6"></div>
   <div class="slot" id="col-7"></div>
   <div class="counter"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
    for(let i = col.length-1; i < col.length; i--) {
```

I starts from the max and goes down to infinity...
The stop condition should not be `i < col.length` (which will always be true) - you want it to stop when the last column has reached (index zero)!

Comment: I don't know why I don't see these things. smh

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {...}
```